# jQuery short if/else in properties

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, if-statement, shortcut

I'm using lot of `$("#foo").css("bar", "baz");` in if/else statements to apply my option changes to my application (jQuery mobile). My question is, is there a shorter way to write that? Something like `$("#foo").css("bar", ((foobar == foobaz) ? "bazbaz" : "bazfoo"));`

Or would it be better (performance) to delete / create objects in DOM while laoding the home page to realize options in jQuery mobile on device?

Comment: Why are you programatically changing lots of CSS? Is it some sort of theme switch? Sounds like it would be better to have classes and use jQuery to add/remove/change the class, and have the actual definitions in a CSS file.

Comment: It's not a "normal" theme switch, the concerned objects are additional features that the user can enable / disable if he wants to, I'm currently changing the display with `.css(display, none)` do you think it's better to add a class like "hidden" which is defined in the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes definitely either use a class or use jQuery's `.hide()` and `.show()`. The hide and show functions do the same as `.css('display' ..)`

Comment: Why didn't I thought about that...
I think this would be the best way to solve it since it also just hides the element so it doesn't matter if something accidentaly tries to operate with it / it's content, should not happen but you could never know.
Thanks!

Comment: No problem, added as an answer to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) would be preferred to lots of `.css('display', ...)`.

The helper functions are cleaner. They essentially do the same thing as setting the `display` as you are currently doing, but it's just more readable. The other benefit of the helper functions is that they will maintain the original display value, whereas manually setting `display`, you would need to know what the original display was when showing it (e.g. block, inline).

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/show/):

> This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block'), except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of inline, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed inline.

Alternatively, create a `hidden` class, and use:

`.addClass('hidden')` and `.removeClass('hidden')` as required.